# Reverse procedure : how to get infinitive when only short passive participle is available

Tags: participle

Is it possible to get infinitive when only short passive participle is available?

If not (which is what I suppose), then how can I **minimize the usage of a dictionary** in order to get the infinitive? And which exceptions will I have to define externally in order to get it right? Probably I will even need to include extra rules for consonant/vowel alternation?

The case when the short participle is ended with -ан is pretty easy for automatic processing : I just replace -ан with -ать. But for other patterns, there is a problem.

There was a question on this site about the choice of -t or -n pattern choice when forming passive participles.

[How to define a general pattern to choose between n-participles and t-participles?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1757/1329)

As one can see, the mapping   verb_infinitive -> pattern is non-injective and surjective, so in order to determine the verb infinitive, I need extra resources.

Comment: ... Can you provide an example of a inperfect passive `-ан` particle?

Comment: @Ark-kun, well, first of all, I am talking about participles, not particles.

Comment: @Ark-kun : think of делан, бран. Right now can't think of any others, but I'll look it up in the corpora.

Answer (score 2):

There might be rules and my kids probably learn them.
I tried to figure it out, and simple patterns come into mind:

> Perfect forms of verbs end with the same vowel as in the participle ending (что сделать?)
>
> Imperfect forms of verbs always end with: -ать/-ять (что делать?)

- -ан -ана -ано -> -ать

сделан сделана сделано -> сделать

прочитан прочитана прочитано -> прочит-ать (что сделать?), прочитыв-ать (что делать?)

- -ат -ата -ато -> -ать

сжат сжата сжато -> сж-ать (что сделать?), сжим-ать (что делать?)

- -ят -ята -ято -> -ять, -ать

смять смята смято -> см-ять (что сделать?), сжим-ать (что делать?)

- -ян -яна -яно -> -ять, -ать

засеян засеяна засеяно -> засе-ять (что сделать?), засев-ать (что делать?)

- -ен -ена -ено -> -ить, -ять, -ать

скошен скошена скошено -> скос-ить (что сделать?), скашив-ать (что делать?)

оставлен оставлена оставлено -> остав-ить (что сделать?), оставл-ять (что делать?)

- -ет -ета -ето -> -еть, -ать

спет спета спето -> сп-еть (что сделать?)

одет одета одето -> од-еть (что сделать?), одев-ать (что делать?)

- -ит -ита -ито -> -ить, -ать

сбит сбита сбито -> сб-ить (что сделать?), сбив-ать (что делать?)

- -ыт -ыта -ыто -> -ыть, -ать

открыт открыта открыто -> откр-ыть (что сделать?), открыв-ать (что делать?)

- -ут -ута -уто -> -уть, -ать

тронут тронута тронуто -> трон-уть (что сделать?), трог-ать (что делать?)

- -от -ота -ото -> -оть, -ать

прополот прополота прополото -> пропол-оть (что сделать?), пропалыв-ать (что делать?)

- -ён -ена -ено -> -ить, -ать, -ять

обозлён обозлена обозлено -> обозл-ить (что сделать?), обозл-ять (что делать?)

взращён взращена взращено -> взраст-ить (что сделать?), взращив-ать (что делать?)

Comment: Everything is just fine with the perfect forms. But the short passive participle of imperfect ones is usually ended with -ем, like e.g. открывать - открываем, not открыт (the same is true for every other example you gave). And sometimes the imperfect verbs have the same vowel as the passive participle, e.g. мыт/крыт <-  мыть, крыть.

Comment: So, I am afraid I won't be able to accept your answer as it is now. However, thanks for effort =)

Comment: Yes, It's a challenge, to analyze what you say every day, not easy to compile rules "on the fly" )

Comment: @petajamaja "imperfect verbs have the same vowel as the passive participle": I think that the full imperfect passive particle forms of `мыть` and `крыть` are `моемый` and `кроемый` and the short forms are `моем` and `кроем` (neither particle is in use).

Comment: @Ark-kun : Well, they ARE in use. And they are present passive participles. While мыт and крыт are actually past passive participles.

Answer (score 1):

There are four types of participles in Russian language. This is how they're formed:

- **Active Present Participle**: suffix `-ущ`/`-ющ` or `-ащ`/`-ящ`; Examples: идущий, дрожащий, заходящий, влияющий, вращающийся, строящийся
- **Active Past Participle**: suffix `-вш` or `-ш`; Examples: заходивший, влиявший, вращавшийся, строившийся, написавший, испугавшийся, пришедший.
- **Passive Present Participle**: suffix `-ем`/`-ом` or `-им`; Examples: вращаемый, изучаемый, образуемый, движимый, несомый
- **Passive Past Participle**: suffix `-?н` or `-т`; Examples: изуч**енн**ый, образова**нн**ый, поби**т**ый, заня**т**ый

You're interested in short passive participles.

To recreate the infinitive verb forms just replace those suffixes+inflections with `-ть` (or `-ти`).

- ем/ом/им -> ть/ти/ь
- т -> ть/ти/ь
- ен/ён -> ать/ять or ить (depending on the verb's conjugation)
- н -> ть/ти/ь

To chose the correct suffix (ть/ти/ь and ать/ять/ить) you need to know the root verb information.

This comprehensive article about participles in Russian language can help you a lot: [http://rusgram.ru/Причастие](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)

**Old answer:**

@BlackBada's answer covered the perfect passive participles.

As for the imperfect passive participles, every participle that I can think of ends with `-ем-ый`,`-ем-ая`,`-ем-ое`,`-ем-ый` suffixes+inflections. The corresponding short forms should have the `-ем`,`-ем-а`,`-ем-о`,`-ем-ы` suffixes+inflections. To recreate the infinitive verb forms just replace those suffixes+inflections with `-ть`:

- читаем -> читать (`Код читаем` - `The code is readable`)
- сжимаема -> сжимать (`Жидкость сжимаема` - `The liquid is compressible`)
- сминаем -> сминать
- засеваем -> засевать

The short imperfect passive participles in masculine form can be ambigous, because they are spelled identical to the verbs in the "2nd person, plural, present tense" form.

Comment: OK, thanks. Nobody seems to talk about exceptions and difficult cases. For example, you did not even mention the verbs ending in -еть, which are actually pretty interesting : петь - пет, терпеть - терпим, греть - грет, видеть - виден etc.

Comment: @petajamaja Well, it's hard to generate those "exceptions and difficult cases". Especially when many forms are rather atrificial and are either not used or don't exist. I don't think that `пет` and `грет` exist.

Comment: >`видеть` - `виден`. What about `видим`

Comment: @petajamaja ohh. I guess I need to also think about "verbal adjectives" versus "participles". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb The boundary between them may seem quite vague, but they are different.

Comment: @petajamaja I rewrote the answer.

Comment: I was a victim of being separated from the living modern russian language for a while. I was relying on archaic forms… Right now, I'll agree that пет and грет are not used.

Comment: @petajamaja The perfect forms `[песенка] спета` and `согрет` are alive though.

Comment: thanks, I know it, I am a native speaker, just an emigrant. And are you Japanese? It is sooo awesome!

Comment: @petajamaja I'm Russian, lol. The nick is from my imageboard past (I've built the Ark that helped survive the global floods/wipes). Imageboards have Japanese origins, so Japanese nicks were common on some boards.

Comment: Wow, are you a civil engineer? Because you're the first person I know who built such an important construction! (You helped prevent floods where? I am from Saint-Petersburg, there is an ark, too, it's called "дамба"). And how is building an ark connected to imageboards?

Comment: My "Ark" was a simple software system developed to fight the virtual imageboard wipes/floods >_< . Basically, imageboards are like forums (there are threads and replies), but much faster and without registration and user accounts. Imageboards only have a fixed amount of alive threads (say, 20 threads). Each time you create a new thread, one thread (with the oldest last answer) is pruned and is lost forever. If someone rapidly creates 20 new threads, all discussions are wiped (the "flood"). My "Ark" software monitored the boards and preserved the important discussions from being swept away.